# Ionic - Firebase Authentication error

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

This is my register-form.component.ts file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Account } from '../../models/accounts/account.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register-form',
  templateUrl: 'register-form.component.html'
})
export class RegisterFormComponent {

  account = {} as Account; 

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private toast: ToastController) {

  }

  async register() {

    try{
      const result = await this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.account.email, this.account.password);
      this.toast.create({
        message: "Account succesfully created!!",
        duration: 3000
      }).present();
      console.log(result);
    } catch(e){
      console.error(e);
      this.toast.create({
        message: e.message,
        duration: 3000
      }).present();
    }

  }  

}
```

When I'm trying to pass AngularFireAuth variable through the constructor it shows this runtime error.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_firebase_app**.app is not a function TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_firebase_app**.app is not a
>   function

I'm new to ionic. please help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to webpack module first. to do that run

> npm remove webpack -g

then Install webpack again

> npm i webpack --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

This problem with angularfire2 versions. First I use angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.4 and I upgraded it to next version and solved the problem

```
npm install angularfire2@next
```